# Live screen capture of text to OCR implementation ideas? (Image to machine readable, Live)

Tags: c#, text, ocr

I am trying to create a software in (preferably) .Net where I can set a fixed area on my screen where text appears and then convert that data into machine readable code using some sort of OCR. I would like to do this on a live basis, meaning when the text changes, I would like my program to be instantly notified of the change and also what it has changed to.

The good thing is that the text is of standard font, color and fixed area.

How should I best implement this? Any third party software recommended for both the snapshotting and OCR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for OCR try tesseract. .net wrappers are also available.